# Oracle: Selecting Records from Hierarchical Data where Child ID=n

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper, hierarchical-data

I have a location table with a unary relationship, and am attempting to set up a view for use as a join in other tables referencing the location table to get the full path up to the root location value. However, after setting up a view with a hierarchical query, I am getting a "When using SYS_CONNECT_BY_PATH function, cannot have separator as part of the column" error message whenever I try to join on the primary key or use that column in the WHERE clause.

Grossly oversimplified example of the table;

```sql
LOCATION_TBL
LOCATION_ID            NAME      TYPE PARENT_ID [etc. . .] 
----------- --------------- --------- ---------
          1 'United States' 'Country'      NULL
          2        'France' 'Country'      NULL
          3    'Washington'  'Region'         1
          4     'Normandie'  'Region'         2
          5       'Seattle'    'City'         3
          6         'Rouen'    'City'         4
```

The create view statement;

```sql
CREATE VIEW v_locationPath AS (
    SELECT location_id
           SYS_CONNECT_BY_PATH(name,'/') AS path
    FROM   location_tbl
    START WITH parent_id IS NULL
    CONNECT BY PRIOR location_id=parent_id
    );
```

Selecting directly from the view with no WHERE clause returns the expected result;

```sql
SELECT location_id,path FROM v_locationPath;

LOCATION_ID                                PATH
----------- -----------------------------------
          1                    '/United States'
          2                           '/France'
          3         '/United States/Washington'
          4                 '/France/Normandie'
          5 '/United States/Washington/Seattle'
          6           '/France/Normandie/Rouen'
```

However if I try to select a single record from the view, limited by a location id value

```sql
SELECT location_id,path FROM v_locationPath WHERE location_id=3;
```

I receive the error. I have double checked, and none of the name values contain the separator being used ('/' in this example).
The following queries have also returned the same error;

```sql
SELECT a.location_id,b.path
FROM   location_tbl a
JOIN   v_locationPath b ON a.location_id=b.location_id
WHERE  a.location_id=3;
   ------------------------------------------------
WITH limitedLocations AS (
    SELECT location_id
    FROM   location_tbl
    WHERE  location_id=3
)
SELECT a.location_id,b.path
FROM   limitedLocations a
JOIN   v_locationPath b ON a.location_id=b.location_id;
```

I have also tried encapsulating the hierarchical query of the view as a subquery in the view itself;

```sql
CREATE VIEW v_locationPath AS (
    SELECT location_id,path
    FROM   (
           SELECT location_id
                  SYS_CONNECT_BY_PATH(name,'/') AS path
           FROM   location_tbl
           START WITH parent_id IS NULL
           CONNECT BY PRIOR location_id=parent_id
           )
    );
```

Attempting the same select statements all return the same error message. Fiddling around, I was able to get a result to be returned, with the value I would expect, however, a record was returned for each row in the location table;

```sql
WITH limitedLocations AS (
    SELECT 3 AS location_id
    FROM   location_tbl
)
SELECT a.location_id,b.path
FROM   limitedLocations a
JOIN   v_locationPath b ON a.location_id=b.location_id;

-Returned-
LOCATION_ID                        PATH
----------- ---------------------------
          3 '/United States/Washington'
          3 '/United States/Washington'
          3 '/United States/Washington'
          3 '/United States/Washington'
          3 '/United States/Washington'
          3 '/United States/Washington'
```

I'm a bit stymied, the error message itself doesn't seem to make any sense, since the location_id isn't in the SYS_CONNECT_BY_PATH column, nor do any of the name values contain the separator value.

--Edit--

Found the problem: not an issue with the query at all (at least not the structure). Turns out there was a record that contained the separator value in the name column.

The data would more accurately look like this:

```sql
LOCATION_TBL
LOCATION_ID            NAME      TYPE PARENT_ID [etc. . .] 
----------- --------------- --------- ---------
          1 'United States' 'Country'      NULL
          2        'France' 'Country'      NULL
          3    'Washington'  'Region'         1
          4     'Normandie'  'Region'         2
          5       'Seattle'    'City'         3
          6         'Rouen'    'City'         4
        ...             ...       ...       ...
       4500     'Blighter/'    'City'         3
```

When I was testing the Select statement for the view in Oracle SQL Developer, the program was executing the query, while only returning the first 50 or so rows. Since it didn't throw any error, I erroneously assumed that all of the records were fine.

Once I actually ran a query to check for the existence of the separator in the name column:

```sql
SELECT * FROM location_tbl WHERE name LIKE '%/%';
```

I found the errant record. After swapping the separator argument for one not found in the location table, the queries worked fine.

As for SQL Developer not throwing the error, when I went back and ran the original select statement again, I did eventually get an error by scrolling down the results table, until it tried to return the record containing the separator value. The WHERE location_id=n, must have just been forcing it to look through the entire result set before returning any records.

Comment: Works like a champ for me. What version of Oracle are you using? [dbfiddle here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=6081fe3214bda01f9038b60628968ba9)

Comment: @BobJarvis: I'd have to double check the Oracle version (10 something I think), was working on this late in the day, then wrote this post from memory after getting home, so it's entirely possible that this is just an ID10-t error on my part.

Comment: Eeeeeeew! 10 is just plain twitchy. I can't be more specific than that, but 10 was/is the worst release of Oracle I've ever worked with.

Answer (score 0):

As I explained in my edit, the problem was a name value containing the separator value '/', I didn't catch it because Oracle SQL Developer only returns a subset of a query's results unless you scroll through them.